# Get only filename from full path of a file

Tags: powershell

I want to split the path and just save the file name `test.xls` in a new variable

```
$namearray = "C:\Users\z003m\Desktop\Service_Tickets\automationscript\vbs\Newfolder\test.xls"
```

Comment: `$newVariable = Split-Path $namearray -Leaf`

Comment: How are you getting to `$namearray`? If you're using `Get-ChildItem` you can get the file name from that...

Comment: @gms0ulman you should post your suggestion as an answer as it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recommend using the built-in `Split-Path`:

```
$newVariable = Split-Path $namearray -Leaf
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the .Net implementation

> **[System.IO.Path]** is 10 times faster than the **split-path** cmdlet

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('c:\myFile.txt')
# result myFile.txt

[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('c:\myFile.txt') 
# result myFile
```

**Performance comparision: 50.000 items**

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(...)    Average: 12,84143 

Split-Path                            Average: 113,537884
```

Comment: This is a poor way to do this, using `Split-Path` is much more efficient.

Comment: I changed my post. Can you delete your comment?

Comment: `Split-Path` supports multiple PowerShell providers; it splits paths for a lot more than just file system names. This would account for some of why it's (meaninglessly, unless you are splitting thousands of names per second) slower than the .NET implementation.